# Algorithm to monitor file changes

Tags: algorithm, http, curl, pattern-matching, batch-processing

What's a good way to monitor and find the optimal times when specific files on remote sites change? I want to limit how often we have to download a file by finding the pattern of when the file is *generally* updated...

1. We download files (product feeds) with data ranging from 1Mb to 200Mb on a regular basis
2. Some of these files are updated every hour, some a few days a week, others once a month
3. The files aren't *always* updated at the exact same time, but there's generally a pattern within a certain period
4. We only want to download the files when we know they've changed
5. We want to download the files as soon as possible after they've changed

A simple way to solve this would be to check the files using a HTTP `HEAD` request every hour and trigger the download when we notice a change in `Last-modified` or `Content-Length`. Unfortunately we can't rely on the HTTP headers as they're generally missing or give no indication as to the actual time/size of the file. We often have to download the whole file just to determine if it's changed.

First I thought I could write a process that checks the file every 1, 2, 4, 8, ... hours (doubling for each iteration) until it found that the file had changed and then just stick with that number. This probably works, but it's not optimal.

To optimize it a bit I thought of tweaking the interval number to find a sweet spot. Then all kinds of scenarios started appearing where my ideas would fail - such as weekends and public holidays when the files wouldn't be updated because people aren't at work. There *is* a pattern, but there are exceptions to it.

Next I started reading about "step detection" algorithms and soon realized I was way out of my depth. How do people solve these problems?

I'm guessing the solution will involve some form of data history, but I fumble with how to optimize the algorithm that collect the data and how to derive the pattern. Hoping someone has dealt with it before.

Comment: Do you have access to run a script on the remote site?

Comment: Nope. No control of any of the sites where the files are stored.

Comment: you can't without downloading something to compare to in the first place.  using curl you can always download the same part of a file at constant index N, and compare it to the previously downloaded part.  If the file was changed, you would most likely see a change since adding or removing something from the file will result in the displacement of the rest of the data.

Comment: the obvious issue is if something is added behind your index, you won't see a change.  so after the file changes, N should be changed so it downloads the endmost part of your file.

Comment: Thanks Thou, I will consider that strategy. Sounds useful. The files are generally dynamically generated and I'm suspecting it wouldn't be appreciated if we requested a snippet every hour, since the source would still need to generate the whole file.